# Why does a very small number return 'inf' instead of the real number?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I run the update of two variables (`H1` and `H2`) which are expected to give similar result but just one of them (`H2`) encounter `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars` from 35th iteration. I tracked and found that there is a part in `H` equation can return `1.48219693752e-323` while `H2` return `inf` which causes all equation error at that iteration .

`1.48219693752e-323` is in the range between `(-1.79769313486e+308, 1.79769313486e+308)`. Why does one of them return `inf`? What is happened here?

---

Extra info:

```
for it in xrange(36): # for 35 iterations
    for k in xrange(kk):
        for j in xrange(jj):
            # update auxiliary
            gamma = H
            gamma2 = H2
            # update H
            H[k,j] = (gamma[k,j]/(2*lagrange)) * \
                     (( np.sqrt((sum(W[:,k]))**2 + \
                     (4*lagrange)*sum(V[:,j]*W[:,k]/np.dot(W[:,:],H[:,j]))) ) - \
                     sum(W[:,k]))
            H2[k,j] = (gamma2[k,j]/(2*lagrange)) * \
                     (( np.sqrt((sum(W[:,k]))**2 + \
                     ((4*lagrange/H2[k,j])*sum(gamma2[k,j]*V[:,j]*W[:,k]/np.dot(W[:,:],H2[:,j])))) ) - \
                     sum(W[:,k]))
            print H == H2
            print "for H: ", it, gamma[k,j], V[:,j]*W[:,k], sum(gamma[k,j]*V[:,j]*W[:,k])
            # gamma2[k,j] changes to be inf at 35th iteration but gamma[k,j] is fine
            print "for H2: ", gamma2[k,j], V[:,j]*W[:,k], sum(gamma2[k,j]*V[:,j]*W[:,k])
```

If you wonder why it should give similar result because `H2` has `gamma2[k,j]` in sum (which should be pull out as coefficient) and should be divided by `H2[k,j]`(the term in front of sum) as `H2=gamma2`.

Comment: Could you update your code such that it is runable -- what are for instance `kk`, `jj`, and `lagrange`?

Comment: @ThomasKühn Thanks so much. I update my full code here.

Comment: Check if any of your dot operations is returning a zero (or close enough).

Comment: May I still ask what the purpose of the lines `gamma = H` and `gamma2 = H2` is?

Comment: @ThomasKühn I want to prove two ways of updating `H[k,j]` so I make `H2[k,j]` as the alternative. I expect the `H` and `H2` to have a similar result (reason in the last paragraph of question). It, of course, can be different but it should not be error.

Comment: My question was what you are using `gamma` and `gamma2` for. They are identical to `H` and `H2`, respectively, so you could also just use `H` and `H2` straight away. However, if your purpose is something else, you might have an error there ...

Comment: @ThomasKühn Oh sorry. Because the gamma is auxiliary variable which is happened to equal H in this update rule. In the future, it might be something else, so I code separately. It is not an error.

Comment: if H[k, j] is in the order of 1E-323, then `((4*lagrange/H2[k,j])*sum(gamma2[k,j]*V[:,j]*W[:,k]/np.dot(W[:,:],H2[:,j]))))` might produce an overflow somewhere, here `(4*lagrange/H2[k,j])` for example

Comment: @armatita I think you are right. Although both algorithm has elements so close to zero, the second is prone to error because it has extra denominator. Thanks everyone here.